# Retrieving the value from a merged, named range via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the value from a merged, named range in Excel however it keeps throwing up exceptions.

If you merge the cells from B2:F10 and then give them a named range of `ExampleRange'

The following code fails to retrieve the value:

```
ExampleVar = Range("ExampleRange").Value
```

However, if I did the following (I don't want to use this method) it works perfectly fine:

```
 ExampleVar = Range("B2").Value
```

How can I get the named range version to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ExampleVar = Range("ExampleRange").Cells(1,1).Value
```